# Since some users want to merge IT Management with Project Management, should all IT Management questions be tagged as "IT Management"?

Tags: discussion, beta

The advantage of using tags like "IT Management" to tag questions related to that subject is so the community can experiment with different types of questions to see if they fit the constraints of this site.  If they don't fit within those constraints, the posts can easily be moved by tag.

Should questions we're not sure about also be marked with a tag that identifies the question as possibly not fitting?  Would this be a good way to experiment with different topics without forcing the question of their relevancy to be answered right away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see IT Management as a kind of 'domain' - like Construction Management, etc.  That said, I still think there is a need for that kind differentiation also.  I agree with Mark - there's no limit on the number of tags or their combination.

So, should this site reserve tags of the form *xyz-management* for the domain *xyz*?

Comment: It would be really interesting if certain questions could be marked as shared across multiple domains.  After all, the website names are the ultimate form of tagging.  StackOverflow and ServerFault contain two separate topics, worth 100% separation.  But Construction Management and IT Management both share commonalities with Project Management, yet still justify their own sites.  Thus, a really cool feature for the Stack Exchange network would be to share questions across domains, such that any question in it-management.com could also appear in pm.stackexchange.com!

Comment: Interesting.  Hadn't thought about it that way.  I winder if this has been asked as a feature request on the main SO site?

Comment: I asked on Meta StackOverflow:  [Is It Possible to Create Multiple Stack Exchange Sites that Share Some Questions and Answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79222/is-it-possible-to-create-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-that-share-some-questions)

Answer (score 3):

Given the back story of the Stack Exchange site family, I imagine that Project Management will end up having lots of users from the IT area. I think that it would be very useful to distinguish IT-specific questions from general ones through tagging, yes.

Having said that, I am not sure that the way to achieve that is having a single [it](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/it) tag. Maybe we can have that, plus some other specialised ones such as [scrum](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrum) or [agile](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agile), becaue there are going to be heaps of questions about managing Scrum and Agile teams, probably.

Answer (score 1):

An IT tag would be useful, as would more specialized tags -particularly since there's no limit on number of tags or their combination.