# Is Project Management Stack Exchange Ready for Public Beta?

Tags: discussion, beta

There are currently a lot of questions right now regarding the domain of Project Management.  Based on the answers to the below questions, it seems that Project Management should consist of any field where there exists a project manager.

- [Since some users want to merge IT Management with Project Management, should all IT Management questions be tagged as “IT Management”?](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14/since-some-users-want-to-merge-it-management-with-project-management-should-all)
- [Please avoid very broad, beginners' questions during the beta](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21/please-avoid-very-broad-beginners-questions-during-the-beta)
- [Is IT Management on or off topic?](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8/is-it-management-on-or-off-topic)
- [Are questions about Product Management on or off topic?](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7/are-questions-about-product-management-on-or-off-topic)

What is the general evaluation of the site so far?  Are there any other questions that should be answered before this is moved to a public beta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Project management is, by nature, a cross-discipline discipline. While there are specific questions for specific domains (eg. IT project management), most of us can benefit from (and contribute meaningfully to) questions in other domains.

Comment: I couldn't agree more!  In fact, I think I might learn something about how to be a better software project manager by learning how project managers in other fields face challenges!